# Jquery value change live

Tags: jquery, html

Please refer this HTML.

```
<input type="text" name="amount1" value="10" />
<input type="text" name="amount2" value="5" />
<input type="text" name="total" value="" disabled="disabled" />
```

Please refer this code.
what I exact want.
when I type some value (int) in amount1 textbox,
that value automatically show in total box,

when I put some value to amount2,
total should show (amount1+amount2) = value

I tried with this jQuery, but did not resolve my problem

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#amount1').keyup(function() {
     $('#total').html('<input type="text" name="total" style="width: 49%;" value="' + $(this).val() + '"/>');
    });
});
```

can anyone help me. 
great!

Answer (score 4):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cht29o60/2/)
It require to add `class` to the input so you can add as much input as you want and avoid a list of `names`, if you don't need it with a simple edit you can make it works with your html
**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" class='amount' name="amount1" value="10" />
<input type="text" class='amount' name="amount2" value="5" />
<input type="text" name="total" value="" disabled='disabled' />
```

**JS**:

```
var total = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Calculate the first total once the page is loaded
    $('input.amount').each(function () {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $('input[name="total"]').val(total);

    //Each time the input value change(right click, keyboard, any) recalculate the total
    $('input.amount').on('input', function () {
        total = 0;
        $('input.amount').each(function () {
            var amountInfo = parseInt($(this).val());
            amountInfo = (amountInfo) ? amountInfo : 0; //Check if number otherwise set to 0
            total += amountInfo;
        });
        $('input[name="total"]').val(total);
    });
});
```

Comment: This answer is indeed more flexible than other here, including mine. Why not use `isNaN()` though ? Just asking for my personnal information though as I can't seem to find any problem with this function.

Comment: @Bartdude `(amountInfo)` checks `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, empty string (""), `0` or `false`...and laziness, it's shorter :D

Comment: Fair enough indeed; Thanks for further explanation. +1 for answer

Comment: I agree with @Bartdude. Your approach better than us and I think must be accepted as answer. Additionally it deserve 1 point.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing id's in your HTML and the way you input the value is a bit strange. Try this instead :

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="amount1" name="amount1" value="10" />
<input type="text" id="amount2" name="amount2" value="5" />
<input type="text" id="total" name="total" value="" disabled="disabled" />
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#amount1,#amount2').keyup(function() {
    var total = parseInt($('#amount1').val()) + parseInt($('#amount2').val());
 $('#total').val(total);
});
```

});

**And the fiddle for this**

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2g322x5/1/)

Note that You need to cast your (text) values to integer to get the calculation right. This is why I use `parseInt()`. If you need to input floating point numbers, you'll need to replace this cast with `parseFloat()` method. You might also want to check if the entered value is indeed a number, which can be done in different ways, one of them being the `isNaN()` method (isNotaNumber => returns true if the value is not a number)

Answer (score 0):

Why add the input as HTML? Just use $('#total').val([value you want]);

Use this code:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#amount1, #amount2', function() {
    var sumAll = parseInt($('#amount1').val()) + parseInt($('#amount2').val());
  $('#total').val(sumAll);
});
```

And don't forget to add id in input elements like this:

```
<input type="text" id="amount1" name="amount1" value="10" />
<input type="text" id="amount2" name="amount2" value="5" />
<input type="text" id="total" name="total" value="" disabled="disabled" />
```

And that is better to use parsInt() function to sure about integer type.

You can see fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/QMaster/8gthskvb/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#amount1').keyup(function() {
        $('#total').val(parseInt($(this).val(), 10) + parseInt($('#amount2').val(), 10));
    });
    $('#amount2').keyup(function() {
        $('#total').val(parseInt($(this).val(), 10) + parseInt($('#amount1').val(), 10));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="40px">1</td>
        <td>Number</td>
        <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Number</td>
        <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt2" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Number</td>
        <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt3" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="summation">
        <td  colspan ="2" align="right">
            Sum :
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id='sum1' name="input" />
        </td>
        </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JQuery part,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        //this calculates values automatically 
        calculateSum();

        $(".txt").on("keydown keyup", function() {
            calculateSum();
        });
    });

    function calculateSum() {
        var sum = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        $(".txt").each(function() {
            //add only if the value is number
            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
                $(this).css("background-color", "#FEFFB0");
            }
            else if (this.value.length != 0){
                $(this).css("background-color", "red");
            }
        });

        $("input#sum1").val(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
```

Fiddle : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/35At5/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="amount1" name="amount1" value="10" />
<input type="text" id="amount2" name="amount2" value="5" />
<input type="text" id="total" name="total" value="" disabled="disabled" />

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#amount1').keyup(function() {
   $('#total').val(parseInt($('#amount1').val())+parseInt($('#amount2').val()));       

   });
});
```

here is your solution as you have not used id tag because jquery works with IDz and CLasses which you haven't difined. so i have re-recreated your solution hopefully its simple and you can understand it btter.

Regards
Imran Qasim
Perfect Web Solutions

[Working Link](http://jsfiddle.net/kgo74Lgm/)

Comment: i did this just for simplicity your method is also correct.

Comment: This dooesn't answer the question as there is no addition made, it's not triggered by both amount fields and the absence of typeCasting would result in errors if ever the addition was done.